# Recursive function for counting divisible digits in C

Tags: c, recursion, division

I need to write a recursive function which accepts a number, and it needs to check whether each number is divisible with the previous number. For example, if the input is 63542, result should be 2, while only 6 is divisible by 3, and 4 is divisible by 2. These are the only numbers that are divisible with the their previous number. I have the following code, but it returns every time one more. For the above example it should return 2 but it returns 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int deliv(int num)
{
    int temp = num%100;
    int counter = 0;

    if(num == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if((temp/10)%(num%10) == 0)
    {
        counter++;
        return counter + deliv(num/10);
    }
    else return counter + deliv(num/10);
}

int main()
{
    int result = deliv(63542);
    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about numbers like 8421.  Does that return "2" for the pairing of 8,4 and 2,1.  Or does it return "3" to include "4,2" as well?

Comment: @selbie it should return 3.

Comment: Also - your program will crash if "num" passed into deliv is a multiple of 10.  Try passing in "5000" instead of "63542" and see what happens.

Comment: @selbie any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change your test condition from `if(num == 0)` to `if(num < 10 )` because if num is a single digit number, temp becomes 0 since `temp = num/10`, which is divisible by `num%10`.
Also, add this condition to avoid crashing when two consecutive digits are 0.

```
if(num < 10)
{
    return 0;
}
//To avoid crash due to 2 zeroes
else if(temp==0)
{
    return counter + deliv(num/10);
}
else if((temp/10)%(num%10) == 0)
{
    counter++;
    return counter + deliv(num/10);
}
else return counter + deliv(num/10);
```

Comment: But it will never be less than 0.